# Part of a Wigner theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, symmetry, hilbert-space

I was trying to understand why there should exist operator in Hilbert space to correspond to any symmetry transformation and found about [Wigner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner's_theorem). In it, I can see that any transformed vector in Hilbert space can be represented as a linear combination of transformed base vectors leading to something like, action of any operator on the specific state can be expressed as the action of this operator on the base states.
How this proves existence of the operator I do not see. It seems to me that this operators is linear or antilinear but this is given it actually exists. Am I missing something? Can anyone point out part of the theorem which proves pure existence and not the properties of the operator?
So to add something, symmetry only tells us ho a ray is transformed into another ray, it does not tell us which of the vectors of the old ray went into which of the new one. Where in the Wigner theorem can we see proven that such a connection can be established?

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0779  "Two elementary proofs of the Wigner theorem on symmetry in quantum mechanics"

Comment: I found a proof which firstly states that in order to prove theorem for any vector we must assume it to hold for unit vectors.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The theorem says "If you have a symmetry, then it's given by an (anti-)unitary operator". You seem to be asking for the existence of the symmetry itself, which is a *given* in the theorem.

Comment: I dont think that theorm only says that. For a given symmetry there exists an operator in Hilbert space. Symmetry itself is not in Hilbert space. Its property is merely to preserve probability.

Comment: And to "preserve probability" it has to live on the projective Hilbert space at least, since that's where probabilities are computed (i.e. it has to be a ray transformation, cf. the Wikipedia article on Wigner's theorem).

Comment: So, we define a ray transformation and to this ray transformation we prove that there exist a vector operator, unitary and linear or anti....?

Comment: Or to be precise, a symetry transformation IS  ray transformation?

Comment: So, for a given symmetry, how to know exactly which vector from the old ray went into which in the new one if there was such a process in the first place?

Comment: so, could we say that because vectors in the old basis have the same coefficients as the vectors in the new basis, we can associate those with the same coefficient and establish correspondence which defines operator via its action on the basis?